# How to register natives and use its function with JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I tried to realize callback mechanism from Java into C++.

At first, im starting an Android-activity with intent from C++ with the following code:

```
jclass class_intent = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
jmethodID newIntent = env->GetMethodID(class_intent, "<init>", "()V");
jobject intent = env->NewObject(class_intent, newIntent);
jstring actionString = env->NewStringUTF("GET_VERSION");
jmethodID setAction = env->GetMethodID(class_intent, "setAction", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;");
env->CallObjectMethod(intent, setAction, actionString);
jmethodID startActivityMethod = env->GetMethodID(ccloc, "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(activity, startActivityMethod, intent);
```

Activity has started successfully. But result of activity is not returned. So, it need to realize callback mechanism.

I tried to create a new function:

```
void myFunc(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    Logger::Instance().LogInfo(L">>> AddInNative.myFunc");
}
```

This function can help to take result of the started activity. I register this function as native using JNI:

```
static JNINativeMethod native_methods[] =
{
    { "myFunc", "()V",  (void*)&myFunc}
};
jint res = env->RegisterNatives(ccloc, native_methods, 1);
```

So, in this example, res equals to 0 (registered successfully). Also I checked correctness of the registration with help of:

```
jmethodID check = env->GetMethodID(ccloc, "myFunc", "()V");
```

So, the method "Check" has found. Therefore, the registration of the method was successful.

And now I'm trying to call this function in my Java-activity:

```
public native void myFunc();
public void FinishActivity(boolean success, Intent intent) {
    Log("FinishActivity");
    setResult(success ? RESULT_OK : RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
    if (mService != null)
        mService.stopSelf();
    Log("Callbacking...");
    try {
        myFunc();
        Log("Callbacked.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log("Exception of callback");
    }
    finish();
}
```

The program is stoped at the myFunc calling position. It is logged "Callbacking...", but not logged "Callbacked." or "Exception of callback".

Please, help. Why is myFunc not called? (mb called, but crashed at this moment...)

Comment: No output in the Android logcat? Did you attach a breakpoint to the native method?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

I add the following code in the Gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
    }
}
```

And also I copy my .so files into 'src/main/jniLibs/[platform]/' directories.

Platforms: arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x64, x86.